# How to fix "Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage" in android studio with emulator on mac yosemite?

Tags: java, android, macos, operating-system, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run an app in Android Studio on Mac. I'm using a mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5.

I've installed everything that I need, like: sdk, emulator avd, etc.

I'm getting the following output:

```
10:09   Emulator: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
10:09   Emulator: Referenced from: /Users/macoutlet/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
10:09   Emulator: Reason: image not found
10:09   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I am also facing exactly same problem

Comment: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64
Dyld Error:
  Lib not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Android/*/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found

Comment: found some hint here, but still it say one after other missing http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2018/08/missing-coreimage-framework-in-macos-yosemite-10-10-5-quartz-framework.html

Answer (score 2):

I have an old 10.9.5 version, so I linked the file to place asked by the software :
In a  terminal :

```
sudo ln -sfv /System/Library/Frameworks//QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework
```

And it worked !

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by updating Mac OS Yosemite to Mac OS Catalina.

This issue was because
Apple's internal system frameworks and libraries get moved around between major releases. In MacOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite), the CoreImage framework is not in /System/Library/Frameworks, but it is in /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework

Answer (score -3):

Install Genymotion on Mac will take care off all setting